# Can run IntelliJ theme plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, themes

I'm trying to create a theme plugin for IntelliJ. I created a plugin project using the template and then try to run the plugin. A new instance of IntelliJ starts and I can open or create a new project. After that all windows closes and I can see this in the log:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -Xmx512m -Xms256m -ea -Didea.config.path=/Users/magnus/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/plugins-sandbox/config
>   -Didea.system.path=/Users/magnus/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/plugins-sandbox/system
>   -Didea.plugins.path=/Users/magnus/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/plugins-sandbox/plugins
>   -Didea.classpath.index.enabled=false -Didea.required.plugins.id=com.magnusottosson.theme.snazzy -Didea.smooth.progress=false -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Dapple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=61675:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath
>   "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/openapi.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/extensions.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/bootstrap.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ
>   IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea.jar" com.intellij.idea.Main WARNING: An
>   illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal
>   reflective access by com.intellij.ide.ClassUtilCore to field
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.fileCache WARNING: Please
>   consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   com.intellij.ide.ClassUtilCore WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to
>   enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
>   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future
>   release 2019-10-13 21:13:37,271 [   1920]   WARN -
>   i.mac.MacOSApplicationProvider - com/apple/eawt/AboutHandler 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/AboutHandler   at
>   com.intellij.ui.mac.MacOSApplicationProvider$Worker.initMacApplication(MacOSApplicationProvider.java:58)
>     ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.apple.eawt.AboutHandler   at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:282)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 17 more 2019-10-13 21:13:40,875 [   5524]   WARN -
>   s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: VibrantInk from
>   plugin: com.intellij.database  2019-10-13 21:13:40,876 [   5525]
>   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: WarmNeon
>   from plugin: com.intellij.database  2019-10-13 21:13:40,876 [   5525] 
>   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: High
>   сontrast from plugin: com.intellij.database  2019-10-13 21:19:13,656 [
>   338305]  ERROR - .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl -
>   com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameDecorator.decorate(IdeFrameDecorator.java:43)
>     ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.apple.eawt.OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:282)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 136 more 2019-10-13 21:19:13,658 [ 338307]  ERROR -
>   .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:13,659 [ 338308]  ERROR - .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:13,659 [ 338308] 
>   ERROR - .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:13,663 [ 338312]  ERROR - .impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:13,966 [ 338615] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameDecorator.decorate(IdeFrameDecorator.java:43)
>     ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.apple.eawt.OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:282)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 132 more 2019-10-13 21:19:13,968 [ 338617]  ERROR -
>   tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:13,968 [ 338617]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:13,968 [ 338617] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:13,969 [ 338618]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:14,024 [ 338673] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - null 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowManagerImpl.appendUpdateToolWindowsPaneCmd(ToolWindowManagerImpl.java:1722)
>     ... 2019-10-13 21:19:14,025 [ 338674]  ERROR -
>   tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:14,027 [ 338676]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:14,027 [ 338676] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:14,028 [ 338677]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:14,178 [ 338827] 
>   ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.DaemonListeners$MyProfileChangeListener.lambda$profilesInitialized$0(DaemonListeners.java:524)
>     ... 2019-10-13 21:19:14,180 [ 338829]  ERROR -
>   llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:14,181 [ 338830]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:14,181 [ 338830] 
>   ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:14,181 [ 338830]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:14,935 [ 339584] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - null 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.intellij.cloudConfig.StatusBarInfoManager$MyStartupActivity.runActivity(StatusBarInfoManager.java:74)
>     ... 2019-10-13 21:19:14,936 [ 339585]  ERROR -
>   tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:14,936 [ 339585]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:14,936 [ 339585] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:14,936 [ 339585]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:15,023 [ 339672] 
>   ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - Assertion failed 
>   java.lang.Throwable: Assertion failed     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:180)
>     ... 2019-10-13 21:19:15,024 [ 339673]  ERROR -
>   leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:15,024 [ 339673]  ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:15,024 [ 339673] 
>   ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:15,024 [ 339673]  ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:15,112 [ 339761] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFrameDecorator.decorate(IdeFrameDecorator.java:43)
>     ... Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.apple.eawt.OpenURIHandler     at
>   com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:282)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 34 more 2019-10-13 21:19:15,113 [ 339762]  ERROR -
>   tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:15,113 [ 339762]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:15,113 [ 339762] 
>   ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:15,114 [ 339763]  ERROR - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:15,313 [ 339962] 
>   ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - Assertion failed 
>   java.lang.Throwable: Assertion failed     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:180)
>     ... 2019-10-13 21:19:15,313 [ 339962]  ERROR -
>   leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3  Build
>
> ## IU-192.6817.14  2019-10-13 21:19:15,313 [ 339962]  ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - JDK: 13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
>
> VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation  2019-10-13 21:19:15,314 [ 339963] 
>   ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - OS: Mac OS X  2019-10-13
>   21:19:15,314 [ 339963]  ERROR - leEditor.impl.EditorsSplitters - Last
>   Action: WelcomeScreen.OpenProject  2019-10-13 21:19:20,161 [ 344810]
>   WARN - .intellij.diagnostic.VMOptions - VM options file not configured

Comment: It's recommended to run the sandbox IntelliJ IDEA instance under the same Java Runtime as the main IntelliJ IDEA. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879. JBR 11.0.4 is recommended, Java 13 may not work. You can change the runtime either in the project SDK configuration or per run/debug configuration via the JRE field. JetBrains runtimes can be found at https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jbr. Try the latest available version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! I could use the SDK shipped with IntelliJ but I had to change the Internal Java Platform from 13 to 11 at File -> Project Structure -> SDK ->IntelliJ IDEA IU-192.6817.14